# Big O vs Big $\Theta$ during coding interview

Tags: time-complexity, big-o-notation, ambiguity

Almost every time I see an article about time or space complexity, people are expressing the complexity with Big O, whereas it should be $\Theta$. 
From the book "Cracking the coding interview":

> "In industry (and therefore in interviews), people seem to have merge Θ
>    and 
>    together. Industry's meaning of big O is closer to what academics mean by
>   Θ
>   , in that would be seen as incorrect to describe printing an array as $O(n^2)$. Industry would just say this is O(N)"

In an interview context, would it be considered ok to say $\Theta$ instead of O?
If the interviewer is asking : "What's the Big O of this algorithm?", is it alright to answer :"The time complexity of this algorithm is $\Theta$(n)"? 
I'm wondering if most interviewers would think I'm trying to outsmart them by saying that. But I don't feel comfortable by replacing O by $\Theta$ since they don't have the same meaning.

Comment: $\Theta(n)$ implies $O(n)$ so you can just say "The time complexity of this algorithm is O(n)" and be formally correct while providing the answer they expect (assuming that your remark about the use of asymptotic notation in industry is correct).

Comment: If I'm the interviewer, you have a ++ on the chart if you handle Landau symbols correctly.

Comment: I don't this is ontopic here: you don't want the computer scientists, but rather the hiring comitee perspective. Not sure where to send you, but I'm pretty sure here is wrong.

Comment: I think you forgot a word in your sentence. Could you please reformulate? I'm not sure to understand what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an answer from reddit that I found the most useful:

> I guess I would say, if someone says, "what's O of insertion sort?", you want to say "it's $O(n^2)$". Sure it's not precisely the same thing as saying that it's "$\Theta(n^2)$ in the worst case", but it's a convention that everyone understands, and it takes less time to get the words out of your mouth.

Comment: "what's O of insertion sort?" doesn't even make sense.

Comment: I guess he meant "What's the time complexity of insertion sort"

Answer (score 1):

I think its fine. It just shows the interviewer you actually know what the real meaning of big-O and theta are. Just make sure its actually true (the $\Omega$ part) when you have a complicated algorithm and you have used some inequality for big-O complexity proof.

Answer (score 1):

If you mention big-theta many interviewers will think you are wrong because they never heard of it. If you then start debating it, then you fail at what the interview is primarily about: Convincing the interviewer that they want to work with you.

Question: You check if X is a prime by testing divisibility by 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 etc. What is the Big-O of the time complexity? If you answer “it’s big-Theta”, what will my opinion of you be?

Comment: It makes sense in the case where the interviewer ask explicitly for Big O. Do you still think it would be a bad idea of answering "Big-Theta of this algorithm is ..." if the interviewer only ask about the time complexity, without mentioning the word "Big O"?

Comment: It’s a risk. Big-O is correct. And I gave an example where Big-Theta is _not_ correct.

Comment: The Big Theta of the algorithm for primality testing is $\Theta(sqrt(n))$ (with n the number of input to test). 
Big O is $O(sqrt(n))$ but also $O(n), O(n^2) ...$ or whatever Big(O) such as $O(f(n)) \subseteq O(sqrt(n))$
It's correct to say this algorithm has a time complexity of $O(n)$, but that's not what the interviewer is expecting.
He's expecting the lowest Big O, thus Big Theta.

Comment: I made a mistake in my previous comment, I meant "or any $O(f(n))$ such as $O(sqrt(n)) \subseteq  O(f(n))$"

Comment: It would depend highly on the nature of the work. If the company seeks critical thinkers and good communicators, explaining the issue *to a good standard* may go in your favour. Hiring managers may not always be experts or the ones responsible for set questions. In highly authoritarian companies which seek code monkeys however, it may not. It may also not go in your favour if you strike the wrong tone, even if you are right - although again, the smarter the company, the greater the latitude likely to be allowed for savants, who will be sandwiched amongst genial and tolerant managers.

Comment: If using mathematics correctly is a problem in the interview, you don't want to work for that company.